# Modifying the help center to better reflect our purpose

Tags: discussion

So, in our most recent [meta question](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/484/is-a-question-about-the-nature-of-education-topical), we tried to determine whether or not [this question](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/6625/difference-between-a-bachelors-degree-and-a-masters-degree-in-cs) is topical to the site.

Gypsy Spellweaver [pointed out](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/487/27):

> Without a change to the Help Center text it's off topic. The Help Center does emphasize the teaching aspect, even going so far as to minimize the need to be a classroom environment.

And a quick look at our Help Center shows that he's [quite obviously correct](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  The relevant language from the link is this (emphasis mine):

> In general, Computer Science Educators Stack Exchange is a place to ask questions about **how to teach concepts** in computer science, computer organization, or software engineering. Generally, these are questions about teaching in a classroom, but this is by no means a requirement. People teach in many environments, and any questions about teaching CS are on-topic here.

> Even questions about how to self-teach are allowed, but be careful that the question is not just asking about the topic itself.

The limits of **"how to teach concepts"** are very real, and we have never held ourselves to them.  We have large classes of questions that simply don't fit those criteria, but they have historically (and repeatedly) been well-received by the community.  In fact, many of them are from our early days when our topicality was being developed and honed.  We have always had, and accepted, such questions.

There are many questions that are not about *how* to teach, but are, rather, about *what* to teach.  For instance:

- [What to consider when choosing version of Python?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/80/what-to-consider-when-choosing-version-of-python)
- [Is it more effective to teach low level languages before high level ones or vice versa?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/212/is-it-more-effective-to-teach-low-level-languages-before-high-level-ones-or-vice)
- [Command-line Java in AP CS A](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/153/command-line-java-in-ap-cs-a)
- [Programming curriculum for elderly students](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/203/programming-curriculum-for-elderly-students)
- [What program follows "hello, world"?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/349/what-program-follows-hello-world)

There are also many questions about the *nature of computer science education* in some important way.  As a few examples:

- [Best Practices / Effective Strategies For Building Diversity In High School CS Programs](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/104/best-practices-effective-strategies-for-building-diversity-in-high-school-cs-p)
- [What qualities should be considered when designing a front end project?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/108/what-qualities-should-be-considered-when-designing-a-front-end-project)
- [How to get girls more interested in computer science?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/129/how-to-get-girls-more-interested-in-computer-science)
- [What are the merits of including the history of computers in the entry level curriculum?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/180/what-are-the-merits-of-including-the-history-of-computers-in-the-entry-level-cur)
- [Colors in Blocks-based Languages](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/448/colors-in-blocks-based-languages)
- [Demographics in Programming Teams in Early CS Courses](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/437/demographics-in-programming-teams-in-early-cs-courses)
- [Video Games during class](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/335/video-games-during-class)
- [How to avoid getting emotionally attached to my students' projects?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/251/how-to-avoid-getting-emotionally-attached-to-my-students-projects)

The questions I linked to were all definitely well received (5 or more upvotes, and not a single downvote among them.)  Very few of the questions were ever *hot*, so that means that the votes were also largely by site regulars, not by drive-by visitors.  These are strong indications that the questions I've linked to are considered topical by the large majority of our userbase.

By my rough estimation, and ignoring questions that simply get closed, ***about 40% of the questions on the site are not about how to teach a concept.***

It seems obvious to me that the Help Center definition is not reflective of who we are and needs an update.  It is silly to leave a definition up that designates nearly half of our well-received questions as off-topic.

We are a small community, so we don't need scores of upvotes to this question to make a change, but we do need some.  Answers could also include proposed language that more aptly describes what topicality entails here at CS Educators.  Alternatively, if you have downvoted this proposal, you might answer with how to deal with questions like the ones I've pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

### CS Educators is a site for questions:

- of **CS Educators**, answered
- by **CS Educators**, and useful
- for **CS Educators** later.

Questions which CS Educators have, which are likely best answered by other CS Educators, and are likely to benefit CS Educators later are the "target" for the site. If the best information is probably *not* from a CS Educator, rather from an Academic Advisor, Career Counselor, or InfoSec professional, it's probably not a good fit here.

There have been a few meta questions about [scope](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-scope) before, including:

- [Are questions about self-learning on-topic?](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23/104)
- [Site scope refinement: high level student problem](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/87/104)
- [Site scope refinement: internet safety](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/93/104)
- [A student on the educators site](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/134/104)
- [SITE::Scope.resolution->choice(Student.access->block(net))](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/449/104)

One additional question, not targeted above yet quite relevant to this question is [Site scope thoughts](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/172/104).

Upon reading my own words from time gone by, I'm surprised to see that a) my thoughts remain unusually constant and consistent, and b) this question remains. I'm also slightly worried about repeating myself too much. As clarity in brief is certainly *not* one of my strong suits, I'm firmly stepping away from suggesting edits to the Help Center. Reviews of ideas and proposals, however, I'm more than willing to assist with.

The Help Center article might benefit from additional clarity. That clarity, however, ought to be such that the motivating question remains off-topic while admitting most of the example questions. Of the sample questions presented, a few actually do fall outside what I consider the *proper* scope for the site, (without respect to question quality):

- [Best Practices / Effective Strategies For Building Diversity In High School CS Programs](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/104/104)
- [How to get girls more interested in computer science?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/129/104)
- [Colors in Blocks-based Languages](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/448/104)

A few of the sample questions did receive answers which would make them seem out of scope. The question's topicality, however, shouldn't be judged on the ability of other to answer the scope of the question.

All other aspects, and my thoughts, are collected and articulated in the *Site scope thoughts* question listed above.